# How to properly set OneSignal as a destination in Segment (segment.com), and also how to set external user ID of OneSignal through Segment

Tags: analytics, onesignal, segment-io, react-native-onesignal

I am trying to implement `Segment` tag management system (segment.com) in my react native app. I have successfully implemented it with source as RN app, and destinations like `Voucherify` and `Firebase Analytics`. I had previously implemented `OneSignal` with it's APIs to my RN app.

Now, I was trying to implement `OneSignal` as a destination of `Segment`. But, it's not clear for me how to set `external user ID` of OneSignal through Segment. All the data I send through `Segments identify call` comes in the `tags` section of OneSignal. The `external user ID` section remains blank for a user record that came through Segment.

So, my question is, how to set `external user ID` of OneSignal through Segment. Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set onesignal external user ID after user logged.

```js
 Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
      OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse(response => {
        if (response && auth.isLogged) {
          OneSignal.setExternalUserId(auth.user._id);
        }
      });
```

This is a simple example from my projects. But you can use everywhere what you want.

```js
  OneSignal.setExternalUserId("_externalUserId");
```

After this setting, the id you set will appear on your panel.
[image]